# QuerySet function in Python doesn't return a string

Tags: python, django

I created a function in Python that converts the QuerySet information into a string. But it isn't working as expected, it does recognize there's an object but it doesn't convert it to string.

Function:

```
def __str__(self):
return f"{self.id}: {self.origin} to {self.destination}"
```

My python shell:

```
>>> from flights.models import Flight
>>> flights = Flight.objects.all()
>>> flights
<QuerySet [<Flight: Flight object (1)>]>
```

Instead of the last line, I should be getting "Flight: 1: New York to London"

Comment: Where is that `__str__` method located? Also, did `import flights.models` run _after_ you made changes to your code, or are you using an existing interpreter sessions with imports that pre-date your code changes?

Comment: Does Django's documentation indicate that `QuerySet.__repr__` uses the models `__str__` method instead of its `__repr__`? Unless it does, you almost certainly need to define `__repr__` instead.

Comment: This __str__ is located models.py of the flights app.

Comment: The problem is very simple and it is because you should end the python shell by ctrl+c, then save the file and restart the sever in another port using `python manage.py runserver 5000` and then again start the shell through the command `python manage.py shell` and check then it will work.

Comment: When I try to do the ctrl+c it says "keyboard interrupt" and doesn't end the python shell...

Comment: @Angely It would end the python shell not the powershell or cmd.

Comment: Plz add code of Flight model